# Getting rid of empty and zeros arrays in a list of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, filtering

I'm considering some Python data that are lists of arrays in the form:

```
LA=
[array([  99.08322813,  253.42371683,  300.792029  ])
array([  51.55274095,  106.29707418,  0])
array([0, 0 ,0 , 0, 0])
array([ 149.07283952,  191.45513754,  251.19610503,  393.50806493, 453.56783459])
array([ 105.61643877,  442.76668729,  450.37335607])
array([ 348.84179544])
array([], dtype=float64)]
array([0, 0 , 0])
array([ 295.05603151,  0,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([ 295.05603151,  307.37232315,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([  91.86758237,  148.70156948,  488.70648486,  507.31389766])
array([ 353.68691095])
array([ 208.21919198,  246.57665959,  0,  251.33820305, 394.34266882])
array([], dtype=float64)]
```

In my data I get some 
empty arrays:

```
array([], dtype=float64)]
```

and arrays filled with zeros:

```
array([0, 0, 0])
```

How can I get rid of both kind of arrays in an automated simple way to and up with

```
LA=
[array([  99.08322813,  253.42371683,  300.792029  ])
array([  51.55274095,  106.29707418,  0])
array([ 149.07283952,  191.45513754,  251.19610503,  393.50806493, 453.56783459])
array([ 105.61643877,  442.76668729,  450.37335607])
array([ 348.84179544])
array([ 295.05603151,  0,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([ 295.05603151,  307.37232315,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([  91.86758237,  148.70156948,  488.70648486,  507.31389766])
array([ 353.68691095])
array([ 208.21919198,  246.57665959,  0,  251.33820305, 394.34266882])
```

Finally I would like to remove the zeros as well keeping the array list format to get

```
LA=
[array([  99.08322813,  253.42371683,  300.792029  ])
array([  51.55274095,  106.29707418])
array([ 149.07283952,  191.45513754,  251.19610503,  393.50806493, 453.56783459])
array([ 105.61643877,  442.76668729,  450.37335607])
array([ 348.84179544])
array([ 295.05603151,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([ 295.05603151,  307.37232315,  451.77083268,  500.81771919])
array([  91.86758237,  148.70156948,  488.70648486,  507.31389766])
array([ 353.68691095])
array([ 208.21919198,  246.57665959,  251.33820305, 394.34266882])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show us your code.

Answer (score 5):

Using NumPy and a list comprehension:

```
>>> from numpy import *
```

**Solution 1:**

```
>>> [x[x!=0] for x in LA if len(x) and len(x[x!=0])]                          
[array([  99.08322813,  253.42371683,  300.792029  ]),                                           
 array([  51.55274095,  106.29707418]),                                                          
 array([ 149.07283952,  191.45513754,  251.19610503,  393.50806493,                              
        453.56783459]),                                                                          
 array([ 105.61643877,  442.76668729,  450.37335607]),                                           
 array([ 348.84179544]),                                                                         
 array([ 295.05603151,  451.77083268,  500.81771919]),                                           
 array([ 295.05603151,  307.37232315,  451.77083268,  500.81771919]),                            
 array([  91.86758237,  148.70156948,  488.70648486,  507.31389766]),                            
 array([ 353.68691095]),                                                                         
 array([ 208.21919198,  246.57665959,  251.33820305,  394.34266882])]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
>>> [x[x!=0] for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]                          
[array([  99.08322813,  253.42371683,  300.792029  ]),                                           
 array([  51.55274095,  106.29707418]),                                                          
 array([ 149.07283952,  191.45513754,  251.19610503,  393.50806493,                              
        453.56783459]),                                                                          
 array([ 105.61643877,  442.76668729,  450.37335607]),                                           
 array([ 348.84179544]),                                                                         
 array([ 295.05603151,  451.77083268,  500.81771919]),                                           
 array([ 295.05603151,  307.37232315,  451.77083268,  500.81771919]),                            
 array([  91.86758237,  148.70156948,  488.70648486,  507.31389766]),                            
 array([ 353.68691095]),                                                                         
 array([ 208.21919198,  246.57665959,  251.33820305,  394.34266882])]
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
In [56]: %timeit  [x[x!=0] for x in LA if len(x) and len(x[x!=0])]                     
10000 loops, best of 3: 176 µs per loop                                                          

In [88]: %timeit [x[x!=0] for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]                                   
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.7 µs per loop   

#@gnibbler's solution:

In [82]: %timeit [x.compress(x) for x in LA if x.any()]                                          
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

---

Timing results for larger arrays:

```
In [140]: LA = [resize(x, 10**5) for x in LA]                                                    

In [142]: %timeit [x[x!=0] for x in LA if len(x) and len(x[x!=0])]                               
10 loops, best of 3: 26.7 ms per loop                                                            

In [143]: %timeit [x[x!=0] for x in LA if count_nonzero(x) > 0]                                  
10 loops, best of 3: 26 ms per loop                                                              

In [144]: %timeit [x.compress(x) for x in LA if x.any()]                                         
10 loops, best of 3: 42.7 ms per loop                                                            

In [145]: %timeit [x.compress(x) for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]                                
10 loops, best of 3: 45.8 ms per loop                                                            

In [146]: %timeit [x[x!=0] for x in LA if x.any()]                                               
10 loops, best of 3: 22.9 ms per loop                                                            

In [147]: %timeit [x[x!=0] for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]                                      
10 loops, best of 3: 26.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you time my answer too?

Comment: @gnibbler `compress` one took around 138us.

Comment: When you're using `count_nonzero`, you don't need the the `len(x)` check.

Comment: aha...`any` is the slow part. `count_nonzero` is _much_ faster

Comment: @gnibbler I actually expected it to be faster, i.e it should short-circuit like Python's `any` does. BTW I resized all items to `100000` and timed again and this time `[x[x!=0] for x in LA if x.any()]` came out to be fastest, and shockingly `[x.compress(x) for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]` was slowest.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, that makes sense. I didn't think `any` would be that slow for the short arrays though

Answer (score 5):

a list comprehension should do the first part

```
[x for x in LA if x.any()]
```

You can do the second part with `compress`

```
[x.compress(x) for x in LA if x.any()]
```

Faster version based on Ashwini's idea

```
[x.compress(x) for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]
```

**Timing:**

```
In [89]: %timeit [x.compress(x) for x in LA if count_nonzero(x)]  #clear winner                                
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.2 µs per loop
```